# Showing $\ell^1$ is a vector space

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\ell^1$ denote the set of those real sequences $x=(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|$ is finite.

Show $\ell^1$ is a vector space and that $\|x\|_1=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j|$ is a norm on it.

Comment: What have you tried? You could start with the definitions of a vector space and a norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ell^1$ is a subset of the vector space $\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb{R}$ so all the stuff about having addition being commutative, associative, and so on, come for free. The only things you need to show is that the zero vector is in $\ell^1$ and that $\ell^1$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.
The first and last are easy.

To show that $\ell^1$ is closed under addition, you first show that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ is a norm. The triangle inequality is the only "hard" part here. You need to show that

$$\lVert (a_n) + (b_n) \rVert_1 = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n + b_n| \le \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n| + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |b_n| = \lVert (a_n) \rVert_1 + \lVert (b_n) \rVert_1. $$

This isn't too difficult. The other properties defining a norm are also easy.

From the triangle inequality, $\ell^1$ is closed under addition since if $\lVert (a_n) \rVert_1 < \infty$ and $\lVert (b_n) \rVert_1 < \infty$ then

$$ \lVert (a_n) + (b_n) \rVert_1 \le \lVert (a_n) \rVert_1 + \lVert (b_n) \rVert_1 < \infty. $$

Answer (score 2):

Take $x,y \in \ell^2$. Now consider $x+y = (x_n+y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. By the triangle inequality $||x+y||_1 =\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n+y_n| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (|x_n|+|y_n|) = ||x||_1 +||y||_1 < \infty$ (so the triangle inequality is satisfied, and $\ell^1$ is closed under addition. Similarly we may proce that $||\alpha||_1 =|\alpha| ||x||_1$. So $\ell^1$ is also closed under multiplication with a scalar.

Also note that $||x||_1=0 \Leftrightarrow |x_n|=0$ hence $||\cdot ||_1$ is a norm.